# How to work with schema returned by 'get_catalog_schema_as_spark_schema'?

Tags: aws-glue-spark

Example:

```
schema = glueContext.get_catalog_schema_as_spark_schema(database=args['Database'], table_name=args['Table'])
```

if I simply print the returned schema I can see the StructType/StructField structure, something similar to:

```
StructType(
    StructField(column1,StringType,true), 
    StructField(column2,StringType,true)
)
```

The object itself is java object and it does not seem to match StructType described in https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/blob/master/awsglue/gluetypes.py

if I try to iterate through `fields` property, it throws error that fields is not iterable.

How do I work with this object? Ideally I want to either be able to convert it into JSON, or atleast get the list of columns.

I appreciate any help here.

Comment: if you just want list of columns have you tried converting dyf to df and then doing columnNames = df.schema.names

Comment: I don't want to read columns from dyf, I want to be able to use the schema that I read from dataCatalog instead.

Comment: what are you planning to do with it after reading?

Comment: I was hoping to use it as a way to store schema to process my data. Its a long story, I found a workaround to my problem, but still very curious of how could I possibly work with that schema object?

Comment: @GSazheniuk what was your workaround? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @YoelMonzon hi, I would read a sample of my destination data (10 rows), then compare column-by-column data types of my new data to that sample and cast any differences to the expected type.